# How to make an animation that moves infinitely right, down, left, and up?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make an animation that moves infinitely to the right, then down, then to the left, and then up (in a loop).

Can you please help me? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Hope this one will help you out to achieve your goal.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes example {
  0%   {background-color:black; left:0px; top:0px;}
  25%  {background-color:black; left:200px; top:0px;}
  50%  {background-color:black; left:200px; top:200px;}
  75%  {background-color:black; left:0px; top:200px;}
  100% {background-color:black; left:0px; top:0px;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**For Your Information:** The @keyframes rule specifies the animation code. The animation is created by gradually changing from one set of CSS styles to another.

Answer (score 2):

[For more information on CSS Animation](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes example {
  0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
  25%  {left:100px; top:0px;}
  50%  {left:100px; top:100px;}
  75%  {left:0px; top:100px;}
  100% {left:0px; top:0px;}
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is actually very easy using css animations.

This is the code for the animation you're looking for:

This will make sure your object will first move to the right, then down, etc...

```css
@keyframes animation_example {
  0% { transform: translate(0, 0); }
  25% { transform: translate(100px, 0); }
  50% { transform: translate(100px, 100px); }
  75% { transform: translate(0px, 100px); }
}
```

Than you need to set the animation of your element. The `infinite` will make sure that the animation will never and and the `5s` are the total duration of the animation.

```css
.your-element {
  animation: animation_example infinite 5s;
}
```

If you want you can check out my little codepen that I created as an example: https://codepen.io/IlijazM/pen/mdPjqbv?editors=0100